# Whats the equivalent of (dx11) structuredbuffer in webgl2?

Tags: webgl, webgl2

I'm porting a directx hlsl script to webgl 2, but I cannot find the equivalent of a structuredbuffer. 
I can only see a constant buffer which are limited to 64k size and use aligning. Should I split the structuredbuffers to constant buffers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more-or-less equivalent in OpenGL land of D3D's StructuredBuffers are [Shader Storage Buffer Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object). However, WebGL 2.0 is based on OpenGL ES 3.0, which does not include SSBOs.

Comment: Tnx, I'll have a look if it's planned for future releases.